# Regular expression to find the paragraph name in cobol

Tags: java, regex, cobol

I need a **regular expression to match the paragraph name while reading a COBOL file** in java. following are the example for paragraph name..

```
9800-WRITE-SCREEN-A.
C70-WRITE-ABFGRPPARM.
FGH0-REWRITE-ABFGRPPARM. 
8100-FILE-ERROR.
```

thanks

Comment: following are the example for paragraph name..9850-READ-SCREEN-A.,    CBA0-WRITE-SCREEN-A., 8100-FILE-ERROR., 81AD-FILE-ERROR.

Comment: Can you add that to your question as all the formatting is lost?

Answer (score 4):

Many think that because COBOL is old it must be simple... Bad assumption. In fact
parsing COBOL is anything but trivial. You might think scanning a COBOL program to 
identify only
`PARAGRAPH` names should not require a full blown parser --- but it will have its
challenges. Regex alone is not up to the task.

**Here are a few tips and things to be aware of:**

- `PARAGRAPH` names may occur in places other than the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`. Based
  on the names given in your question I suspect you should only analyze the
  `PROCEDURE DIVISION` of the program. This is the last DIVISION of a traditional
  COBOL program (assuming the program does not contain nested programs). 
  If you need to analyze OO COBOL or nested COBOL programs you will need 
  more advanced parsing techniques
  than Regex can provide.
- Limit your analysis to text files containing single programs. It is possible to
  code multiple independent programs in a single source 'deck' but is not commonly
  done, so realize that you probably will not handle this gracefully.
- For Fixed Format COBOL programs (older style coding) you can rely on the fact that
  `PARAGRAPH` names will begin somewhere between columns 8 through 11.
- For Fixed Format COBOL, you need to ignore any text appearing in columns 1 through
  6 and from column 73 to the end of line.
- For Fixed Format COBOL, any line containing a character other than space or hyphen
  in column 7 should be ignored (this is a comment or debug line).
- If the program contains `COPY` or `REPLACE` directives in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`,
  your analysis is going to be incomplete and/or inaccurate. `COPY` can potentially
  bring in additional source code containing paragraph names and the `REPLACE`
  directive can change names of subsequent paragraphs during the text manipulation
  phase of the compile (i.e. the compiled program may have names different from
  the one you detect). This is not a common practice but one you need to be aware of.
- Continuation lines can really mess up a simple text scanner because a single COBOL
  word (e.g. paragraph name) may be split over multiple source lines. However, in the 
  case of paragraph names it is not a common occurrence for them to span multiple
  lines.
- The comma (",") and semi-colon (";") characters are "noise" and can appear almost 
  anywhere a space can occur (at least within the PROCEDURE DIVISION). You 
  might want to replace these with spaces to simplify
  subsequent analysis.
- Quoted text. COBOL has some interesting quoting conventions, particularly when
  quoted text spans multiple source lines. Text quoting and continuation rules
  for COBOL are unlike any other
  language you may be familiar with - and present real headaches for parsing. I'm not
  even going to begin to explain them here!

**How to recognize a `PARAGRAPH` name in the Procedure division of a COBOL program?**
Simple, just look for single "words" delimited by periods ("."). A paragraph name is a single
word (may contain hyphens, alpha and/or numeric characters) and is always preceded by
a period and followed by a period. There may (or may not) be blank spaces before or after 
each of the periods.

Now it seems to me that if you want to identify `PARAGRAPH` names, you probably want to
identify `SECTION` names too. A `SECTION` name is similar to a `PARAGRAPH` name except that
it is followed by the mandatory reserved word `SECTION` and optionally followed by a `PRIORITY NUMBER`. `PRIORITY NUMBER` is not much used any more (in fact
it is obsolete) so you might not have to deal with them.

**A somewhat flawed but reasonable process to identify COBOL paragraph names**

This is not a single Regex, but a process that involves multiple Regex and or
text manipulations.

- Assume Fixed Format COBOL
- Eliminate all quoted text. Not a difficult proposition for simple text but
  when continuation lines are involved it gets quite difficult. If COPY/REPLACE directives
  are involved - forget it!
- Eliminate comment lines (i.e. column 7 contains an asterix)
- Strip out columns 1 through 7 and 73 through to end of line
- Drop all text prior to the words "PROCEDURE DIVISION"
- Replace all occurrences of comma and semi-colon with a single space character
- Extract all text between periods (".")
- If the extracted text contains a single word, then it is a `PARAGRAPH` name.
- If the extracted text contains two words, and the second word is "SECTION", then
  the first word is a `SECTION` name.

The above is not fool proof, but should be good enough to identify paragraph and section names in most "garden variety" COBOL programs.

I wish you luck.

Comment: I always use the compile listing. All the complex "parsing" has been done, accurately, by the compiler. This assumes you have a compile listing :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
"^[ ]{7,10}([-\\w]+)"
```

Paragraph names begin in columns 8-11. $1 will be the name.

Answer (score 0):

Some rules:

1. Paragraph names begin in Area A (columns 8-11).
2. Can contain characters, numbers or hyphens.
3. Ends with a dot(.).
4. No whitespace character.

Regex = ^[ ]{7,10}([-\w]+\.\n)

Comment: Not entirely and fully true. The full-stop/period need not be contiguous with the paragraph-name. OP may not have it, but SECTIONs, which aren't paragraphs, but which would be needed if they exist in the same way that their own paragraphs would be needed, has the word SECTION after the label, and the SECTION must be terminated with a full-stop/period, though, again, it need not be contiguous. You have correctly re-stated what OP has said. You have a regex... of dubious use. Read @NealB's answer first. Then look at the other two answers. Only NealB's answer is any use.